# Was the combination of yoghurt and honey called "the food of the gods" in ancient Indian records?

Tags: nutrition, history, india, honey

From Wikipedia's [article on yogurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogurt#History):

> In ancient Indian records, the combination of yogurt and honey is called "the food of the gods".

All that the [provided reference](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=19C3DnJyWE0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA170&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) states is:

> Whatever the real origin, yogurt is mentioned in records of ancient civilizations from India to Iran; by 500 BCE, holy men on the subcontinent had labelled the delicious mixture of yogurt and honey "the food of the gods".

Is this true? Who are these holy men and where do they label the mixture of yoghurt and honey, "food of the gods"? Where does the date of 500 BCE come from?

Answer (score 1):

well its true in a way....

But the original concoction is called Panchamrita ( cos it has 5 things added ). Yogurt and honey do form large portions. sugar the least...and milk and ghee ( clarified butter ) are also added.

honey, sugar, milk, yogurt, and ghee

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchamrita

This is the food of the gods.....cos it is used during puja. Normally the stuff is later swallowed by the kids etc of the house.....Its a ceremonial blessing thingy and very delicious....but mostly in small quantities.

However, it is also used in large quantites containing mostly milk for big rituals, in which case it is a large waste of milk.....

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhisheka

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). This answer isn't very clear. To English speakers, the link between "panchamrita" and "5 things added" isn't obvious. How does using during puja make it the food of the gods? Whether it is delicious or a waste is subjective. You don't answer when this started.